# Passing data to another after receiving data from call back in react js

Tags: reactjs

I am a beginner in react js so what I want to do it is : 
I want to pass the quizData array to another component ,  data in quizData is set from a callback function which is submitForm function . But when I try to print the prop in another Component(QuizScreen)
it prints 1 as the value console .

Can anybody Please suggest . Am I doing something wrong with the design pattern ?

Thanks in Advance.

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import QuizForm from './QuizForm.js'
import QuizScreen from './QuizScreen';

class App extends React.Component{

state = {
isSubmitted : false,
 quizData : [],

}
submitForm = (data) =>{

  this.setState({isSubmitted : true,
            quizData : this.state.quizData.push(data)  
  })
 console.log("Value of quizData is "+ JSON.stringify(this.state.quizData))
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className= "container">

    {(!this.state.isSubmitted) ? <QuizForm isFormSubmit= {this.submitForm} /> : <QuizScreen details={this.state.quizData}/>}

      </div>


    </div>
  );
}
}
export default App;



import React from 'react'


class QuizScreen extends React.Component {`enter code here`

constructor(props)
{
    super(props)

    console.log("Props is "+JSON.stringify(props.details))

}

render(){

    return(
        <div className= "App">
        </div>
    )
}
}
export default QuizScreen;
import React , {Component} from 'react'
import FileUpload from './FileUpload';
import QuizScreen from './QuizScreen.js'
import  './QuizForm.css'
import InputTextField from './InputTextField';
import fields from './Fields.js';


class QuizForm  extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        value: '',
        fileData : [],
        negativeMarking : 0,
        quizName  : '',
        category :'',
        weightage : 0,
        quizTime: '',
        isSubmitted: false
      };

      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    myfile = (fileUploadData) =>{

      console.log("Hello from myfile"+JSON.stringify(fileUploadData));
      this.setState({fileData : fileUploadData})

   }

    handleChange(event) {

      console.log("My values are "+event.target.name)
      const value =  event.target.value;
      this.setState({[event.target.name] :value })      
      }

    handleSubmit(event) {
      alert('QuizName is '+event.target.quizName.value)
      event.preventDefault();
      this.setState({isSubmitted : true})
      this.props.isFormSubmit(this.state)
    }


    render() {
      return (
        <div className="form-style-6">
          <h1>Create Quiz</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

          {fields.map(form =>{
        return(

            <InputTextField 
            type={form.type} 
            name={form.name}
            _handleChange={this.handleChange}
            placeholder= {form.placeholder}
            key={form.placeholder}
            />
              );

          } )}


           <FileUpload onFileUpload = {this.myfile}/>

          <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
        </div>

      );
    }
  }
  export default QuizForm;
```

Comment: Can you please paste the code in a text format instead of screenshots from your IDE?

Comment: add the QuizForm code

Comment: Hi Michael , added the QuizForm Component

Answer (score 0):

You have to refer the current component scope by putting `this` keyword when you want to access `props`. Plus, print it on your console by calling it inside a `componentDidMount()`.

```
import React from 'react';

class QuizScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('Props is ' + JSON.stringify(this.props.details)); //<-- Here you have to put `this` keyword.
  }

  render() {
    return <div className="App"></div>;
  }
}

export default QuizScreen;


import React , {Component} from 'react'
import FileUpload from './FileUpload';
import QuizScreen from './QuizScreen.js'
import  './QuizForm.css'
import InputTextField from './InputTextField';
import fields from './Fields.js';


class QuizForm  extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        value: '',
        fileData : [],
        negativeMarking : 0,
        quizName  : '',
        category :'',
        weightage : 0,
        quizTime: '',
        isSubmitted: false
      };

      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    myfile = (fileUploadData) =>{

      console.log("Hello from myfile"+JSON.stringify(fileUploadData));
      this.setState({fileData : fileUploadData})

   }

    handleChange(event) {

      console.log("My values are "+event.target.name)
      const value =  event.target.value;
      this.setState({[event.target.name] :value })      
      }

    handleSubmit(event) {
      alert('QuizName is '+event.target.quizName.value)
      event.preventDefault();
      this.setState({isSubmitted : true})
      this.props.isFormSubmit(this.state)
    }


    render() {
      return (
        <div className="form-style-6">
          <h1>Create Quiz</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

          {fields.map(form =>{
        return(

            <InputTextField 
            type={form.type} 
            name={form.name}
            _handleChange={this.handleChange}
            placeholder= {form.placeholder}
            key={form.placeholder}
            />
              );

          } )}


           <FileUpload onFileUpload = {this.myfile}/>

          <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
        </div>

      );
    }
  }
  export default QuizForm;
```

Comment: I m getting output on console as  Props is 1

Comment: Are you sure you set your data properly?

Comment: I have attached the QuizForm component where I am setting the data.